# How can you implement AND/OR logic for tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tags, logic

I have a web application that shows a users all of their data bucketed in to special campaigns. These campaigns can have different 'tags' that belay their purpose (Growth, Retention, Loyalty) many more then I've given here.

What I'm looking for is a way to allow more advanced and intelligent users to create groups of AND/OR clauses that allow them to look specifically for certain campaigns that target their strategy.

My tags are simple, index-based with titles. I can generate a list of the campaigns for a user but I want the actual filtering of the campaigns to happen on the user end because they can download the campaigns. The site will also have such things as 'new' campaign tags and the like.

So if I have a `filterExpression` like "(Retention+Growth)|Loyalty", I should see all campaigns that are tagged with both Retention AND Growth, OR loyalty.

Thoughts?

Right now my logic is causing crossed eyes.

***Edit: Psuedo-Example:***

```
Growth OR Loyalty OR Retention
= 0|1|2

filterPass = [ [0], [1], [2] ]
CampaignTags = [ 1,4,5,6 ]
//This campaign passes because it has "1"


(Growth AND Loyalty) OR Retention
= (0+1)|2

filterPass = [ [0,1] , [2] ]
CampaignTags = [ 1,4,5,6 ]
//Fails because it doesn't have "0" AND "1", OR "2"
```

Comment: I have no idea what your objects nor html nor code looks like so it's extremely difficult to help based on the content of the current question. http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm missing some information or a place where I should be looking for how to implement this. My code wouldn't help here.

Comment: Ok well heres is why I can be of more assistant; I do not know WHAT language you are using to display a website, I do not know HOW you want to create the way for users to do what it is they are doing (Postback, Ajax), and I don't know HOW your data is stored so I can't tell you better way to filter the data.

Comment: ... the question is tagged "JAVASCRIPT", "JQUERY" and "AJAX"... the data comes from SQL but I'd like to do my filtering in javascript to deliver a better product.

Comment: I don't know if this will help - [Parsing expressions in infix notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093138/what-is-the-algorithm-for-parsing-expressions-in-infix-notation)

Comment: What are your tags being represented as in javascript? what are they filtering? where do they come from? what you are doing is definitely possible, but without any help from you in the form of information, noone is going to be able to say much more than that.

Comment: See edits for more information.

Comment: I think people are getting caught up on the fact that you haven't said how the campaigns are ultimately displayed even though that information isn't necessary. I think your question is just "I have a list of entities with tags, how can I filter them using JavaScript and input from the user like '(tagA & tagB) | tagC'".

Comment: @nwelcome - Quite right. I probably should have put the psuedo-code example in earlier as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Parse the expression into infix form, as noted by @dave.
2. Use a recursive algorithm to transform this into [disjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form), that is, has all `|` operators at the top level, and all `+` operators just inside that.  The example you gave above is already in such a form.  Roughly, your algorithm should recursively find terms of the form `x+(y|z)` and replace them with `(x+y)|(x+z)` and flatten nested `+`s and `|`s.
3. You can now check whether a set of tags matches the expression by checking if there is any disjunct whose tags are all affixed to the item in question.

Alternatively, if you need speed, look into [BDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram)s.

Comment: Whooo okay this seems like the stuff I was looking for. It's ugly, but I'll hunker down and figure it out. Thanks!